# Why my Bootstrap 4 tabs don't deactivate?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I click the tabs 1-4, they get active, but they don't deactivate. Once clicked, every tab stays active and highlighted until reloading the page. What should I do to make sure only one tab can be active at the same time?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
        <h2 class="display-4 text-center py-5 my-4">Meet the Speakers</h2>

        <div class="nav justify-content-center nav-pills flex-column flex-md-row">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#stare" data-toggle="tab">Stara baba 1</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#baby" data-toggle="tab">Stara baba 2</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#jebac" data-toggle="tab">Stara baba 3</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#pradem" data-toggle="tab">Stara baba 4</a>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-content py-5">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="stare">Stare</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="baby">Baby</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="jebac">Jebać</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="pradem">Prądem</div>
        </div>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried Bootstrap 4, so I'm not sure if it has any issues. Remember that it is alpha, so issues are to be expected. Your tabs work as expected in Bootstrap 3.3.7, but you'll have to use `ul`. Here is the modified code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
        <h2 class="display-4 text-center py-5 my-4">Meet the Speakers</h2>

        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li data-toggle="pill"><a class="nav-link" href="#stare" data-toggle="tab">Stara baba 1</a></li>
            <li data-toggle="pill"><a class="nav-link" href="#baby" data-toggle="tab">Stara baba 2</a></li>
            <li data-toggle="pill"><a class="nav-link" href="#jebac" data-toggle="tab">Stara baba 3</a></li>
            <li data-toggle="pill"><a class="nav-link" href="#pradem" data-toggle="tab">Stara baba 4</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content py-5">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="stare">Stare</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="baby">Baby</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="jebac">Jebać</div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="pradem">Prądem</div>
        </div>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't change a thing, they still don't untoggle.

Comment: Have you tried the "Run code snippet" button at the bottom of my answer? I see them toggling correctly. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 58 64-bit

Comment: On Bootstrap 3, I suppose, and I want to use version 4 alpha 6

Comment: Yes, my answer is for bootstrap 3. Like I said, bootstrap 4 is still alpha and it is expected to have issues. File an issue to them so they can fix it before the final release.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks for the help, but unfortunately, your answer does help only a little, as I want to use Bootstrap 4's cards.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was only trying to show you that it worked in bootstrap 3 and not 4 which indicates that it is probably a bug in 4 alpha. You can wait and see if somebody else knows some workaround, but it is not recommended to use alpha in production, anyway.

Comment: It's just my personal project, maybe for some people outside. I'm not a professional, just trying to learn by that.

Comment: OK, then I recommend that you continue working on other parts of your project and hopefully bootstrap will move to beta and the issue gets fixed before you finish. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and used this simple fix:

```
$(".nav-link").click( function() {
            $(".nav-link").removeClass("active");
        });
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have the issue with Bootstrap 4.3.1. Bug?

Comment: Issue also present in Bootstrap version 4.4.1